# Fixed image background

Tags: html, css

I have this small piece of CSS code `body { background: url(images/bg.jpg) repeat-x scroll center top; }` but I want the background to always stay fixed as background image instead of being fixed at the top of the page.

What are best practises to achieve this? If you look at the picture below you can see that the background is fixed to the top of the screen instead of being fixed as background image even when you scroll down.

[image]

Comment: add one more line  body { background-size : cover }

Comment: the image explain only what you have written but we want some life example to understand where is the problem in your site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
body { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```